# why null variable assign not null in condition?

Tags: flutter, authentication, navigation

I have a conditional statement to keep logg-in user in flutter after splash screen, that when list is null navigate to login() and when it has value navigate to introduce,
but although list (values_list_r) is null and "a" should be null (and printed null), it considered "not null" in  navigateAfterSeconds and navigate to introduce(), where is my wrong??

```
    void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
        }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
var a;


 String initState() {
 super.initState();
   setState(() {

   //my sqlite class 
   ValuesDbprovider vdbhelper = new ValuesDbprovider();
   vdbhelper.fetchValues();

   //list has returned by fetchvalue() and currently is null and empty
   a =values_list_r.map((e) => e.user_no ).toList();

   //this printed a:  , means a is null
   print("a:$a" );
 });

}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  home: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [Color(0xFFFF1844), Color(0xFFFFD200)])
    ),
    child: SplashScreen(
        seconds: 3,

        //this is conditional statement for navigation 
        navigateAfterSeconds: (a != null ? introduce()  : login()),
        loadingText: new Text('calculator',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontFamily: 'yasamin',color: Colors.white,
          ),),
        image: new Image.asset('images/logo_logo.png'),
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle()
        photoSize: 100.0,
        onClick: ()=>print("wellcome"),
        loaderColor: Colors.white,
    ),
   ),
 );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some best approach if you want to use an array. instead of doing var a, you can just using.

```
List<dynamic> a = [];
```

then in your initState since it doesn't return any `String` value write this instead

```
void initState() {
 super.initState();
   setState(() {

   // Your Sqlite Class
   final vdbhelper = new ValuesDbprovider();
   final dbResult = await vdbhelper.fetchValues();

   // secondary option
   List<dynamic> myData = dbResult.map((e) => e.user_no ).toList();
   a.addAll(myData);

   print("a: $a");
 });
```

Notes : your code is unclear, `a` is will always returning null because it's unclear where the `values_list_r`  comes from. And you are executing a method `vdbhelper.fetchValues();` but doesn't save it into a variable. Ofcourse the `a` will always return null, because it has no source

Comment: Thanks friend for your explain, i did it, also there was a problem belong to async and Future method on initstate(),  but there is my main  problem that it return a =[ ] (null ) that is correct,  but in my statement it define as NOT NULL, and go to the introduce() page.  my statement: navigateAfterSeconds: (a != null ? introduce()  : login()),

Comment: Thank you so much friend, it solved, the problem was belong to n=my conditional statement, i should have used .isNotEmpty method for condition.

Comment: No problem mate, glad to hear that ;)